# Swift - Shows an error for term "inView"

Tags: swift, xcode, view, position

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import Foundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

let coin = Coin()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
        coin.coinFlip(inView view: UIView)

        }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
       }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Xcode will not let me put the "coinFlip" function! It says that I have to put a comma after "inView," and then it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'inView'" . What do I do in this situation?

Comment: You should use **self.view** instead of only **view**

Answer (score 2):

The class Coin doesn't inherit from a class that has a view property. Assuming you want to reference the view in the flip coin method, add an argument to the function to pass it in.

```
func coinFlip(inView view: UIView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!